# Convergence with Supremum Metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let *B*[0,1] be the set of bounded functions on [0,1 equipped with the supremum metric. Let ($f_n$) be the sequence in *B*[0,1] defined by,

$f_n(x)$ = $\Bigg\{$ 1 - $nx$ if 0 $\leq$ $x$ $\leq$  $\frac 1n $ 
or  0   if $\frac 1n$$\leq$ $x$ $\leq$ 1

Prove that ($f_n$) does not converge in {*$B$*[0, 1], *d*}.

After drawing what the graph of the function looks like, I can get a picture of it in my head but I am unsure of what steps to take to prove it. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show that $f_n$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Alternatively, and with more machinery, note that the $f_n$ are continuous, while their pointwise limit is not. The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous

Comment: I have that d($f_n$,$f_m$) = 1 - $\frac mn$ for any n greater or equal to m, does that prove that it is not cauchy?

Comment: @AlbertB: Yes, because for any $n$ you have $d(f_{2n},f_n) = {1 \over 2}$. Hence $f_n$ is not Cauchy. However, qbert's suggestion has more intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $f_n(x) \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$ for any $x\in (0,1]$ and $f_n(0) = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, if $\{f_n\}$ converges to some function $f\in B[0,1]$ in sup. metric, it has to be the function $$f_0(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } x = 0 ,\\ 0, \text{ if } x\in(0,1] \end{cases}$$ since convergence in supremum metric implies point-wise convergence. But then 
$$
\sup\limits_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f_0(x) | \geq |f_n(\frac{1}{2n})| = \frac 12 , 
$$
which contradicts to the assumption that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f_0$ in supremum metric.